# What is this strange view type?

Tags: postgresql

I created a view by mistake using table name as a column. It looks like this

[image]

`create myview as select node from node join othertable using (id)`

I can query it like `select (node).* from myview`

However, there is no documentation about it or at least I dont know how to search.

What have I created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a table a type with the same name is also created. When you put the table's name into the select list, you'll get a single column of *that* type.

Take this table:

```
create table foo (c1 int, c2 text);
insert into foo values (1, 'one');
```

When you run the following select:

```
select foo
from foo;
```

The output is:

```
foo    
-------
(1,one)
```

Note that it's only a single column (named foo).

See [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-USAGE) for details

Comment: Reassuring that I was on the right track with my comment. So ultimately this isn't an implicit cast of the table to a composite type, but rather referencing the table name in the select tells postgres to use the composite type that already exists for the table? That's pretty wild.

Answer (score 1):

You have created a view with a column of type "node" (that in your case is the table).

The PostgreSQL [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/catalog-pg-type.html) states:

> The catalog pg_type stores information about data types. Base types and enum types (scalar types) are created with CREATE TYPE, and domains with CREATE DOMAIN. A composite type is automatically created for each table in the database, to represent the row structure of the table. It is also possible to create composite types with CREATE TYPE AS.

So when you create a table - a new type is added to your database. Using it as function return type, parameter type or a column type in another table/view is totally valid.